# Does rospy not have walltime?

Tags: ros, rospy, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was under the impression that anything in roscpp should also be available in rospy. WallTime is in roscpp but I can't find it in rospy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9571/does-rospy-not-have-walltime?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-03-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospy/Overview/Time

for an overview of how you access time in rospy.  rospy doesn't provide an explicit 'WallTime' because Python comes with the `time` module; in C++, `WallTime` is basically a convenience wrapper around various POSIX and Win32 inconsistencies.

If you wish to convert it to a `rospy.Time` instance you can use:

```
t = rospy.Time.from_sec(time.time())
```

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-08-31**:
So there's no equivalent for setting up `rospy.Timer()` with a callback if there isn't a `rospy.WallTimer()`?